# Access Parent property using Child

Tags: php, oop

How can I get Parent property when I create a new istance of my child. Note that my classes does not need to have inheritance as my purpose for only for them is to show one-to-many relationship. Thanks

```
 class Parent{
     $property;

    //getter and setter
    }

    class Child{
    $parent; //for Parent Type
    }

    myChild = new myChild();
    echo myChild->parent->property;// this line does not work for me
```

Comment: In this code parent property is null until you do something like myChild->property = new Parent()

Comment: Also, echo to test is not the better choice: use var_dump() instead.

Comment: Try var_dump($myChild) and see that property is null.

Comment: Hello, `myChild->property = new Parent() ` on this line ,meaning I have to extend my child to parent?

Comment: No, means you assign the Parent object to the property Child::parent. Extending is "Child extends Parent". But for your purpose you don't need extending, but assigning.you can do (should do) this in the __construct() method as shown in one of the answers you received.

Comment: Ok thanks thanks ,my code works now! :)

Comment: if you don't want to to use inheritance (extends).  The you need to use composition. i.e. assign the parent to  the `Child`. Also, properties should be private to prevent other classes changing them. Because of this `magic` functions are needed to access them how you want. Often `getters` and `setters` are used. Examples of all this : https://eval.in/672777

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_parent_class()` for this. Eg below:

```
<?php

class parent {
    function parent_class()
    {
    // implements some logic
    }
}

class child extends parent {
    function __construct()
    {
        echo get_parent_class($this);
    }
}
$CHILD = new child();
?>
```

Comment: Only in PHP 7 a method may have the same name as the class itself, perhaps, change it to `__construct()` (I meant the method only..)

Answer (score 0):

Use parent::

```
class A {
  function example() {
    echo "I'm parent";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  function example() {
    echo "I'm child";
    parent::example();
  }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();
```

Comment: This is wrong regarding his purpose of showing relationships between objects and not accessing properties of Parent directly from Child. The inehiratsnce, in this scenario, is the wrong choice.